# Network resource unavailable when installing Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable

Tags: visual-c++, installation, visual-studio-2017

When I try to install Visual Studio, I get an error when installing Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable, saying it can't access `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\
{C0B2C673-ECAA-372D-94E5-E89440D087AD}v14.0.24210\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\`

I get the same results when trying to manually install Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable, but with additional errors as well.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Looks like the machine is pretty messed up.  Maybe from a failed previous install, maybe from a beta version, maybe ProgramData is shot to hell.  A thorough cleanup and machine checkout would be wise.  Or use another one.